# Returning results in recursion

Tags: prolog, binary-tree

I am trying to solve a problem where I need to evaluate the value of a binary expression tree.

```
tree_calc(Tree, Eval)
```

where `Eval` should hold the final result and `Tree` must be in the form:

```
tree(LeftNode, Operator, RightNode)
```

If I create the `tree` function as per the form above, how am I supposed to pass the results of the calculations back up the recursion if there isn't an empty variable to store the results?

My understanding is that an extra variable is always needed to store the result in.

Apologies in advance as I am sure  I am misunderstanding something basic.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: You need to think in terms of **relations**: You need to define a *relation* between such a tree and the value. A predicate with two arguments is sufficient to do this. About the only thing you need to define is: What is the relation between a tree, the values of its children (if any), and the value of the tree itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this context, `tree` isn't what you are calling a *function*, nor is it what Prolog would refer to as a *predicate*. `tree(LeftNode, Operator, RightNode)` is just a *term* that is used as a structure to represent the tree. So, for example, `(2 + 3) * 4` would be represented by, `tree(tree(2,+,3), *, 4)`. You would call your *predicate* with `tree_calc(tree(tree(2,+,3),*,4), Eval)` and expect that query to yield, `Eval = 20`. The term, `tree/3` doesn't carry results in this case.

To give an example of how to access `tree/3` in a predicate, here's a simple predicate that evaluates the simplest tree (so there's no recursion to tree leaves):

```
tree_calc(tree(L, Op, R), E) :-
    % Neither L or R are of the form `tree/3`
    compute(Op, L, R, E).

compute(+, L, R, E) :- E is L + R.
compute(*, L, R, E) :- E is L * R.
compute(-, L, R, E) :- E is L - R.
compute(/, L, R, E) :- E is L / R.
```

You can generalize `compute/4`:

```
compute(Op, L, R, E) :-
    Exp =.. [Op, L, R],
    E is Exp.
```

And you can call it like so:

```
| ?- tree_calc(tree(2,+,3), Eval).

Eval = 5

yes
```

For your more general case, you'll need to check `L` and `R` to see if they are a `tree/3` structure themselves and recursively call `tree_calc` recursively if so.

Prolog is good at matching term patters. So if you check unification `L = tree(LL, Op, LR)` and it succeeds, that means `L` is a `tree` with left branch `LL`, operation `Op`, and right branch `LR`. You can play with this behavior at the Prolog prompt to see how it works:

```
| ?- Tree = tree(2, +, 3), Tree = tree(L, Op, R).

L = 2
Op = (+)
R = 3
Tree = tree(2,+,3)

yes
| ?- Tree = tree(2,+,tree(3,*,4)), Tree = tree(L, Op, R).

L = 2
Op = (+)
R = tree(3,*,4)
Tree = tree(2,+,tree(3,*,4))

yes

| ?- Tree = tree(2,+,tree(3,*,4)), Tree = tree(L, Op, R), R = tree(LR, OpR, RR).

L = 2
LR = 3
Op = (+)
OpR = (*)
R = tree(3,*,4)
RR = 4
Tree = tree(2,+,tree(3,*,4))

yes
| ?-
```

Comment: Thanks for that lurker. I just can't seem to get my head around how to define the relations @mat mentioned above. Should `tree` be returning anything at all? Or as you mentioned, is it simply there to represent the tree? Also if the `Tree` variable references `tree(tree(2,+,3),*,4)` am I supposed to be accessing the left and right branches using `Tree` somehow? Will keep thinking about it.. Thanks for your help.

Comment: @Archer even thinking that `tree` might return something is not thinking relationally. Prolog predictes don't return things. They succeed or fail, and in the process, instantiate variables in an attempt to succeed. `tree/3` in this context, as I mentioned, is a term used to define a structure for your data, in the same (loose) sense as a `struct` in C defines a data structure. It doesn't "return" anything. As I described in my answer, you pass in a data structure (using `tree`) to `tree_calc`, and that query will attempt to succeed with a proper evaluation of the expression, yielding `Eval`.

Comment: @Archer see my updated answer for more information about processing a `tree/3`.

Comment: @false in this case, I guess I don't need the parentheses. I had some code at some point where I would get a syntax error if I didn't have them in this kind of context, but don't recall the specifics.

Comment: Thanks so much for your explanation. In the requirements for this question, I have to write the predicate as `tree_calc(Tree, Eval)`. `Tree` will hold something identical to `tree(2,+,3)` as you stated in your example. With this in mind, how would I use `Tree` to access `L` and `R`? Or am I misinterpreting the question and I can simply do as you have done - replace `Tree` with `tree(L, Op, R)`?

Comment: @Archer the last paragraph of my answer explains that. In this case, you'd unify, `Tree = tree(L, Op, R)` to obtain the branches and operator. You can play with some examples at the Prolog command line to get the idea.

Comment: @Archer, I added more examples to my answer to illustrate. You should try these things yourself to gain more understanding.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks so much for taking the time to respond with all that.