# Error: `compute/4' is not a function

Tags: prolog

I am trying to evaluate an arithmetic binary tree.

```
tree_calc(tree(L, Root, R), Eval) :- compute(Root, L, R, Eval).


compute(Root, 'empty', 'empty', Root).
compute(Root, L, R, Eval):- number(L), number(R), E =..[Root,L,R], Eval is E.
compute(Root, L, R, Eval):- 
        L = tree(LL, LRoot, LR), R = tree(RL, RRoot, RR),
        E =..[Root, compute(LRoot, LL, LR, LEval), compute(RRoot, RL, RR, REval)],
        Eval is E.
```

When I run the program with input:

```
tree_calc(tree(tree(empty,2,empty),
             '+',tree(tree(empty,1,empty),
                  '/',tree(empty,2,empty))), Eval).
```

I am getting the error:

```
ERROR: is/2: Arithmetic: `compute/4' is not a function
```

I can't seem to work out why this error is being thrown as I have thought this only gets shown if a function wasn't defined.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While Scott addressed the most technical issue you're experiencing, you could be interested to know about a simpler, declarative, approach:

```
tree_calc(tree(L, +, R), Eval) :- tree_calc(L, Lr), tree_calc(R, Rr), Eval is Lr+Rr.
tree_calc(tree(L, /, R), Eval) :- tree_calc(L, Lr), tree_calc(R, Rr), Eval is Lr/Rr.
tree_calc(tree(empty, N, empty), N).
```

This works under some restricted assumption about the correctness of the tree (for instance, that a leaf is a number, and only specified operators are used):

```
?- tree_calc(tree(tree(empty,2,empty),
             '+',tree(tree(empty,1,empty),
                  '/',tree(empty,2,empty))), Eval).
Eval = 2.5 ;
false.
```

Another approach, since is/2 actually evaluates an expression tree, could be

```
tree_calc(T, V) :- translate(T, E), V is E.

translate(tree(empty,N,empty), N) :- !.
translate(tree(L,Op,R), E) :-
    E =.. [Op,Lt,Rt],
    translate(L, Lt),
    translate(R, Rt).
```

Now all Prolog (binary) arithmetic operators can be used. The cut is required to avoid, on backtracking, to attempt calling univ/2 on an atom...

Comment: Unless the OP has changed their definition of `tree/3`, your first solution should be correct. This is a continuation of their [first post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36197849/returning-results-in-recursion). Now the OP calls the middle argument `Root` which is a little confusing.

Answer (score 0):

`is` is used for arithmetic assignment, not for unification.  (For example, `A=1+1` would not end with `A` being 2, but `A is 1+1` would.)  So Prolog is trying to arithmetically evaluate the expression on the right, which contains what looks like an arithmetic function, but clearly is not.

You could use `=` instead of `is` or, more concisely, eliminate `E` and just unify with `Eval` directly: `Eval =..[Root, compute(`...

Then again, you seem to be using `compute` to return something that is part of a list, so Prolog may not be the only one who is confused.

Comment: Thanks Scott. I actually tried using `=` prior to posting the question. However, this seems to simply write out: `Eval = compute(2, empty, empty, _G413)+compute((/), tree(empty, 1, empty), tree(empty, 2, empty), _G418)`

Comment: If you want `compute` to be a function, define it as such.  If you want it to be a predicate, define it as such.  It can't be both.